# Problem when publishing Nuxt.js app on shared hosting

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, publish

Okay, I'm trying to publish my Nuxt.js app on my web host but I've run into some issues. I do not want a static site.

After running "npm run build" locally, I transferred the files to my web host with FileZilla. Then I'm supposed to fill in the statements shown in the picture below.

[image]

And this is where my problems begin. The app does not want to start at all, and i am nor sure what to put as "Application startup file". And according to my web host, the overall problem is that there is no startup file for Nuxt applications. I am completely new to Nuxt and do not have that knowledge and therefore I now turn to you, is it the case that there is no starup file for Nuxt?
The web host also mentioned that it is more difficult to get a Nuxt application upp and running on shared hosting, is that correct? Will I not be able to get my app up and running in this place?

My web host had received this error message when they tried to start my app. Maybe there are some clues in there to find.

```
    ERROR  Request failed with status code 404                                                                                      15:58:38
  at createError ({{my-adress}}/14/lib/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
  at settle ({{my-adress}}/14/lib/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
  at Unzip.handleStreamEnd ({{my-adress}}/14/lib/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:260:11)
  at Unzip.emit (events.js:315:20)
  at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Why do you **not** want a static site so far? Do you have a lot of password protected pages or any other specific limitations? Also do you plan to have `ssr` set to `true` or `false`? Also, can you give more context as of your platform here? Shared hosting will be totally fine if your project is not planned to host 3000 people at the same time neither is generating a lot of cash. So you can totally run your server-rendered app there (if it supports Node.js of course, but probably does).

Comment: The main reason is that i have a contact form that vill not work on a static site. I am planing to have ssf set to true. No the site is just for a small local buisness, so it wont have many visitors at the same time. I have a Vue app on the host fron earlier so i hoped thos would work as well.  I don't know what more information you need about my platform?

Comment: Is it the only reason? Because a form totally work on a static site. Even an SPA only can use a form just fine. It will be free rather than needing to pay a Node.js server (if you go `target: server`). If it works with a Vue project, it should be fine here too. What's the name of the platform? Also, I still do recommend Netlify for your apps if going full static.

Comment: I use nuxt-mail for the form and as i understand, it will not work on a static site? My web host is a swedish company named Inleed.se. I can not realy deside freely where to put the site, the buisness owner are deciding that unfortunately.

Comment: If you do have a mail server, you will indeed need to host a Node.js server. You could also use a serverless function for this purpose. But, to use a form you don't actually need a backend server nowadays. As shown on [Netlify's documentation](https://docs.netlify.com/forms/setup/). Can't you discuss it with the business owner? I mean, it's paid and it doesn't even have a CDN. So, you're gonna pay, will have more work to do, possibly more errors due to the fact that more code is needed to make it work and on top of that, performance-wise, it will not be as good (in Japan for eg, because CDN).

Comment: Let us know if you achieve to host it there or want it somewhere else. I may **maybe** try to host something there for you. Even if it should be the same as on any VPS server (like Digitalocean or alike).

Comment: Hi, havent had the time to work on this for a while. I will maybe try to piblish on Netlify next week or maybe try a static site after all. And have another sulotion for the contact form, but i dont know how i can solve it in that case.

Comment: Tell me if you need some help.

Answer (score 0):

Without some more context, I can't tell you exactly what your issue is but I suspect it is to do with how the web server on your shared hosting is configured to serve files. When you visit a route, it's not correctly finding that index.html page.

A Nuxt static application deploys with a structure where each page route has its own rendered index.html page inside a folder - if I'm not mistaken.

Your web path may look like **example.com/hello** but in reality it resolves as **example.com/hello/index.html**. Some web servers will struggle by default with this structure if not setup correctly.

Honestly, if I were you I'd deploy the project to either [Vercel](https://vercel.com/dashboard) or [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/).

Both have incredibly generous free tiers that will let you host your application for (if it's not making any money) for a very long time at a good scale.

They both run on automatically scaling infrastructure so you don't need to worry how much resources your site is consuming or how many users you get. It will maintain responsive and reliable without any detriment to load speed.

They'll also automatically handle building and deploying the application on your behalf. All you need to do is connect the service to a Github repository.

They also provide CDN's and other optimisations such as compression for you as well to make your site much faster.

Nuxt has a dedicated page on Netlify deployment. I recommend you give it a read:

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/netlify-deployment/

Answer (score 0):

When you do `npm run build` (or `npm run generate`), your final content will be available in the `/dist` directory (the console should tell it to you at the end). It contains an `index.html` file, this is the one that serves as entry point.

---

Btw, before going any further double check that this is working **locally**:

- `npm run build`
- `npm run start` (URL and port will be given to you)

If it works locally, you can proceed.

---

`.nuxt` is essentially used for development purposes, caching and so on. And should not be tracked by Git, nor deployed.

I'd like to advice against using FTP for deploys (especially if not secured). Prefer a more modern way, like pushing your latest git commit and let the platform handle the hook or fetching your new code and bundling your app for you.

As recommended above, Netlify is one of the best place to easily host your Nuxt app: simple, fast and headache-free. Also, check @jordan's link about the various platform deployments, you may find yours (if it's good/well known).

Comment: I am using nuxt version ```2.17.1``` in my project. When I run the command ```npm run build``` I could not see any ```dist``` folder in my root folder of my project. Only one **dist** folder is exist inside the ```.nuxt``` folder and it does not contain any ```index.html``` file. Did you mean that we must only deploy that ```dist``` folder to the host? Because you said there is no need to deploy ```.nuxt``` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I may come here a little late, but this is the way I configure the "Application startup file" when deploying a Nuxt app in shared hosting using the NodeJS Selector app (that commonly you find in CPanel)

Since basically the startup file in NodeSelector is executed as if you would run `node startup_file.js`, you can create an `app.js` at the root of the project, and add the following code:

```
require('@nuxt/cli').run(['start']);
```

This is basically the same as `nuxt start`, which is basically the `start` script in your `package.json`

Hope this can help others having the same issue. I leave here the same issue posted in git:
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/7192